# Help With Houseplant Identification

Tags: identification, houseplants

I recently purchased this houseplant, but do not know what it is. Can anyone help with ID? US dime for scale.[image: mysterious houseplant]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what it is! Couldn't ID farther than *Selaginella sp.* but that's enough to call it a spikemoss.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose is a Lycopodium (or in any case some species in the same family).

It is a link between mosses and vascular plant. It is still vascular, without flowers but with spores. Not a fern, but defined "Fern ally" (like few other families which very few species, that nobody want to classify correctly).

Note: I could be wrong. Some mosses could be similar (but branches are too long), and also some flowering plant could have similar look, when they are small. On the other hand, I do no remember good-looking (so for pots) flowering plant.